# sh: 1: node-gyp-build: Permission denied and npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 126

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Tried to run this on Ubuntu 18.04 x64. It used to work properly a day ago but it stopped out of nowhere.

```
npm i simple-youtube-api
```

I used to be able to install them but not anyone, im getting this:

```
> bufferutil@4.0.1 install /root/NezukoBot/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp-build

sh: 1: node-gyp-build: Permission denied
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.1 requires a peer of @discordjs/uws@^10.149.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js-commando@0.10.0 requires a peer of sqlite@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/mocha/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! bufferutil@4.0.1 install: `node-gyp-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@4.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-07-02T12_58_27_816Z-debug.log
```

I have tried this but i still get the error:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/153), it's a permission problem. Try running with *sudo*.

Comment: still not working even with sudo

Comment: Delete node_modules folder and re-run *sudo npm install*.

Comment: See this [post](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2610)

Comment: I honestly cant just delete the node_modules folder since i got a ton and i most stuff wont get installed and i dont remember all the module names

Comment: and that ⵍⵢⴻⵙ comment isnt related to my problem

Comment: All the dependencies installed are listed in the package.json file so no problem if you try to delete the node_modules folder and retry to install them with *sudo npm install*

Comment: Can you use something like nvm? If not then at least override your global node_modules folder location. You shouldn't ever need to install stuff in system protected folders.

Comment: @Giingu did you find a solution? I'm having an issue that looks very similar, coming from  `node_modules/ws`.

Answer (score 3):

NPM is careful when installing packages as root.

Installing global packages as root or sudo can potentially damage your operating system, as it may accidentally replace files critical to the operating system itself.

However if you still want to proceed, you know what you are doing and you are e.g. using a virtual machine, you can do.

```sh
npm install --unsafe-perm -g simple-youtube-api
```

See [unsafe-perm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#unsafe-perm) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I solved the problem with permissions using latest version of npm:

```bash
npm i -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try to run the command under a user other than root.

https://timjrobinson.com/fixing-node-gyp-permission-denied-when-running-as-root/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: OR just use `--unsafe-perm` flag on npm.